# Explicit formula for the solutions of a general linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to write the explicit formula of all solutions of a linear system in the form :

$Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix ($n$ different from $m$), $x$ is $n$-dimensional vector and $b$ is $m$-dimensional vector.

Comment: Do you mean m*n matrix?

Comment: I mean n × m matrix (n columns and m rows)

Comment: Ah, Ok, as long as n is for column dimension of the matrix

Answer (score 1):

If $m \ne n$ there is always the possibility that there is no solution.

Assuming that there is a consistent solution.

if rank $A  = n$ i.e. $m>n$ and there are $n$ independent row vectors, then you can construct a square matrix (choosing $n$ independent rows).  Call this matrix $A'$ and $x = A'^{-1} b'$ will be your solution set.

If rank $A < n$ you have a non-trivial kernel.  In which case you will need to find the kernel of $A$ and one point in the solution set.

And the entire solution set will be that the sum of that point with any vectors in the kernel.

If you want to do this "systematically" then put your matrix into triangular form.

Answer (score 0):

Set of all solutions of the system $Ax=b$ can be characterized as follows.

$A$ be a given $m\times n$ matrix.

Define, $$K_H=\{c\in\Bbb R^n:Ac=0\}$$

If $d\in \Bbb R^n$ is a solution of the system $Ax=b$ then set of all solutions (say) $K$  of the system $Ax=b$ are given by the cosets,

$$K=\{d\}+K_H$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of subroutines written in (VBA) Visual Basic for Applications, but it is very easy to translate into any other language.  The first is 'solve_rd_system' and the second is 'reduce_matrix'.  The subrountine 'solve_rd_system' solves any linear system $Q \ x = b $ where $Q$ is $m \times n $.  If there is no solution, then it returns $ierr = 1$.  If there is at least one solution then $ierr = 0$.  If there is a single solution, then $mt=0$ is returned, and the solution will be $x_0$, otherwise $mt$ will be equal to the dimension of the solution space of $Q \ x = 0 $ (the null space of the corresponding homogenous system $Q \ x = 0 $), and $x_0$ will be a particular solution.  Thus, if $ierr = 0$ and $ mt > 0 $, then the system has infinite solutions which are of the form

$ s = x_0 + X u $

where $u$ is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^{mt} $

(Note that in the code, the parameter 'X' is not a vector, but a two-dimensional matrix, with size $m \times mt$.  Its 'mt' columns span the null space of the related homogeneous system $Q \ x = 0 $)

```
Public Sub solve_rd_system(q, b, m, n, mt, x0, X, eps, ierr)
Dim lones(200) As Integer
Dim jt(200) As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer

ierr = 0

For i = 1 To m
  q(i, n + 1) = b(i)
Next i


Call reduce_matrix(q, m, n + 1, eps, det)

For i = 1 To m

    lones(i) = -1
    For j = 1 To n
        If Abs(q(i, j) - 1) < eps Then
            lones(i) = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

Next i

' solve for x0 vector

For i = 1 To n
   x0(i) = 0
Next i

For i = 1 To m

j1 = lones(i)
If j1 <> -1 Then
   x0(j1) = q(i, n + 1)
Else
   If Abs(q(i, n + 1)) > eps Then
      ierr = 1
      Exit Sub
   End If
End If

Next i
tcount = 0
For i = 1 To n

   For j = 1 To m
       If i = lones(j) Then GoTo lnext_i1
   Next j
   
   tcount = tcount + 1
   jt(tcount) = i

lnext_i1:
Next i

For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To tcount
        x(i, j) = 0
    Next j
Next i

For jtndx = 1 To tcount
    x(jt(jtndx), jtndx) = 1

    For i = 1 To m
        j1 = lones(i)

        If j1 <> -1 Then x(j1, jtndx) = -q(i, jt(jtndx))

    Next i

Next jtndx

mt = tcount

End Sub

Public Sub reduce_matrix(a, ByVal m As Integer, ByVal n As Integer, ByVal 
       eps, ByRef det As Double)
Dim change_flag As Boolean
Dim i, j, k, k1, krow As Integer
Dim amax As Double, kmax As Integer


For i = 1 To m
    piv(i) = i
Next i


If display_matrix_flag = 1 Then Call display_matrix(a, m, n)

krow = 1
det = 1

For i = 1 To n
    
k1 = 0

amax = Abs(a(krow, i))
kmax = 0

For k = krow To m

   If Abs(a(k, i)) > eps Then
      If Abs(a(k, i)) >= amax Then
         kmax = k
         amax = Abs(a(k, i))
      End If
      
      
      
   End If

Next k

If kmax <> 0 Then
   k1 = kmax
End If


If k1 = 0 Then
   det = 0
   GoTo lnext_i
End If

If k1 <> krow Then

' interchange rows k1 and krow

   For j = 1 To n

      t = a(k1, j)
      a(k1, j) = a(krow, j)
      a(krow, j) = t

   Next j
   det = -det
   
   
   t = piv(k1)
   piv(k1) = piv(krow)
   piv(krow) = t
   
End If


 '  normalize krow-th row

   t = a(krow, i)

   If Abs(t - 1) > eps Then
   
   For j = i To n
   
      a(krow, j) = a(krow, j) / t
   
   Next j
   
   det = det * t


   End If
   
' eliminate elements in column i

change_flag = False

For i1 = 1 To m

If i1 <> krow Then

   factor = -a(i1, i)
   If factor = 0 Then GoTo lnext_i1
   
   change_flag = True
   
   For j = i To n       
       a(i1, j) = a(i1, j) + factor * a(krow, j)   
   Next j
   
End If

lnext_i1:
Next i1
    
krow = krow + 1

If krow > m Then Exit For

lnext_i:

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here is my comment:

Without specifying $n$ and $m,$ it is possible that there are infinitely many, one, or no solutions to the system $Ax = b.$  For example, if we know that $A$ is invertible, then perhaps the only explicit formula that can be given would be $$ x = A^{-1}b.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my case A is non square matrix, which means it's not invertible

Comment: $A$ is some $n\times m$ matrix. It is absurd to talk about its inverse.

Comment: Right, I was saying *if* $A$ was invertible, meaning $n = m$ and it was full rank.  It remains that we can not say much else without specifying $A$ and $b.$ Is $m > n$ or $n > m?$ If $m > n,$ we have that the system is over determined